# With TLS, Does the Transport layer comes after the DNS and again after the data is ready to add the TCP header?

Tags: ssl, tcp, dns, tls1.3

I understand that TLS requires a reliable transport but following the TCP/IP model the first layer in case of sending data/request would be Application layer ... After connection established and the data is ready it moves to the next layer which is the Transport layer for the TCP header to be added.
So the first step after the DNS would be the TCP handshake then up to TLS handshake then down to TCP again to add the TCP header ? OR I'm missing something here ?

Comment: TLS is at the application layer in the TCP/IP model. TCP does not care about the application payload, so there is no up to TLS and down to TCP again. And DNS is fully separate to it.

Comment: DNS is very loosely related to TLS. DNS happens to map a name to an IP (roughly) and only then does the TCP/IP and then TLS handshake starts. But when you are here, what happened at the DNS level previously is lost. TCP/IP just works with IP addresses (and ports). Then DNS comes a little back into play in the sense that TLS often uses certificates, hence names are coming back into play, as do some extensions like SANs, or OCSP/Certificate logs using URLs and hence names, and SNI, etc.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich But we still start with the TCP for establishing the connection. So TCP opens the stream then whatever happens in the application layer takes it to the other side after adding the TCP header. And this what confuses me, we start with the Transport layer not the application layer. Or maybe to put it right, Transport layer is wrapped around the app layer, it doesn't start after it.

Comment: @t2149573: You are mixing the TCP/IP model with timing behavior. Models are an abstraction for a specific purpose and you are using it for a purpose it was not designed for.  This model has no concept of starting at a specific layer and then moving to another layer. Imagine abstracting a car like this: transport layer are the tires and motor and application layer are the passenger seats. You don't start driving a car with the tires and then moving up to the passenger seats. These are just different aspects of the same moving car.

Comment: On your timing stuff: an application, like a web browser, does not "care" about TCP/IP details. It has HTTP stuff to send to some endpoint. It finds the IP address for that and then asks the OS to open a "socket" and after receiving the confirmation it worked, then send  "inside" it the HTTP stuff. So things happens in different places. The "application" only sees and cares about the application layer if you want, and the OS cares about the lowest levels. This is an oversimplification of course, things are less clear with TLS and more recently QUIC.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with layer models is that there are too many cases when there are either too many or not enough layers. It is important to understand the concept of layers, and why do we need one. But IMHO, neither of the layer models are actually representing the Internet.

As already said in comments, DNS is a separate "application" from the standpoint of what you are describing. So, whether DNS is happening or not does not have an affect of what happens next.

I think this figure shows the layer model with TLS in it ([source](https://blog.eleven-labs.com/en/understanding-ssltls-part-1/)).

[image]

Application is passing its data to TLS layer. This layer is usually implemented as a library that is linked with the application, so it is also "above" sockets.

TLS works on top of TCP, that is TLS gives encrypted stream along with its own signaling packets to TCP and TCP processes them as any other packets.

So, basically it is how you describe. First, a TCP connection is established. After which TCP just sends whatever stream of data TLS is giving it, and this stream starts with a TLS handshake.

There is one nuance though. TCP is a stream based protocol. It accepts stream on one side and returns stream on the other side. Dividing the stream into packets is happening in TCP itself. That is TLS is using "records" of any size which are convinient to TLS. The records do not necessary correspond with packets.

Comment: Same comment above: So we still start with the TCP for establishing the connection. TCP opens the stream then whatever happens in the application layer takes it to the other side after adding the TCP header. And this what confuses me, we start with the Transport layer not the application layer. Or maybe to put it right, Transport layer is wrapped around the app layer, it doesn't start after it.

Comment: we will start with the application that opens the socket to another application (using ip:port) pairs. which involves application telling tcp layer that it wishes a connection to the said ip:port. i am frankly not sure whether application tells tcp layer directly and then put its data though tls or it tells it to tls and then tls tells it to tcp. but this is OS/library implementation detail. socket needs to be created by the application first, then something happens.